# SonarQube-docker : Plugin issue when running with external database

Tags: docker, sonarqube

Running the last SonarQube docker version (7.0), when i using the H2 embedded database, i could see the plugin , but when running the same images with a postgresql database connection, i don't have anymore the plugin

H2 embedded database

```
2018.04.04 13:53:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube    Server / 7.0.0.36138 / 3b827a9a9a4b133c9fbe168aec8db44d78efeaeb
2018.04.04 13:53:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Starting embedded database on port 9092 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:9092/sonar
2018.04.04 13:53:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database started. Data stored in: /opt/sonarqube/data
2018.04.04 13:53:17 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:9092/sonar
2018.04.04 13:53:17 WARN  web[][o.s.d.DatabaseChecker] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: /opt/sonarqube
2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.u.SystemPasscodeImpl] System authentication by passcode is disabled
2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.h.MigrationHistoryTableImpl] Creating table schema_migrations
2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarPython [python] installed
2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarJava [java] installed
2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarTS [typescript] installed
2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarJS [javascript] installed
2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: SVN [scmsvn] installed
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarPHP [php] installed
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarXML [xml] installed
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: Git [scmgit] installed
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin Flex [flex] installed
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarC# [csharp] installed
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Flex / 2.3 / 79167f762219bea1fd181ff5ef6ca4b34abd1675
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarC# / 6.7.1.4347 / c8c4474682a3cd67f345ff46b2a7e1c62c85441c
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarJS / 4.0.0.5862 / 7c3166ea3f0526e74aa53e521d2fee2290fa0820
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarJava / 5.1.0.13090 / 5d2c41b3da0a3a6c11417a6d17d011d7a1fe8ba2
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarPHP / 2.12.1.3018 / 75c2cebff53eeee63fe7eafc5e31c188270d5fe8
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarPython / 1.9.0.2010 / f17988b34c750c96c13ef5bdcc0645167233e3ad
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: Git / 1.3.0.869 / 4da53e3f9e55f4f2e5796625cb0c5768ed152079
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: SVN / 1.6.0.860 / 2111fdbd1dddda4ad6d4ed6486fd0b18c1010d3b
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarTS / 1.5.0.2122 / 7eb12e7593b8e02616914773451c6118f230c57a
 2018.04.04 13:53:18 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarXML / 1.4.3.1027 / 39588245cecf538bb27be4e496ff303b0143d20b
2018.04.04 13:53:19 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.AutoDbMigration] Automatically perform DB migration on fresh install
```

postgresql database

```
 2018.04.04 13:51:27 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.GeneratePluginIndex] Generate scanner plugin index
 2018.04.04 13:51:27 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterPlugins] Register plugins
2018.04.04 13:51:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2018.04.04 13:51:36 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2018.04.04 13:51:38 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.BuiltInQProfileRepositoryImpl] Load quality profiles
```

..

```
 2018.04.04 13:51:48 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
```

Thanks for your support

---

I did other tests:

With a  new postgresql database, without data, when i start the 
docker run  -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=XXXX -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=XXXXX -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://XXXX:1223/dbname sonarqube

the plugin are well loaded

```
2018.04.05 09:09:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: /opt/sonarqube
2018.04.05 09:09:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.u.SystemPasscodeImpl] System authentication by passcode is disabled
2018.04.05 09:09:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.h.MigrationHistoryTableImpl] Creating table schema_migrations
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarPython [python] installed
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarJava [java] installed
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarTS [typescript] installed
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarJS [javascript] installed
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: SVN [scmsvn] installed
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarPHP [php] installed
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarXML [xml] installed
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: Git [scmgit] installed
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin Flex [flex] installed
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SonarC# [csharp] installed
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Flex / 2.3 / 79167f762219bea1fd181ff5ef6ca4b34abd1675
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarC# / 6.7.1.4347 / c8c4474682a3cd67f345ff46b2a7e1c62c85441c
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarJS / 4.0.0.5862 / 7c3166ea3f0526e74aa53e521d2fee2290fa0820
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarJava / 5.1.0.13090 / 5d2c41b3da0a3a6c11417a6d17d011d7a1fe8ba2
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarPHP / 2.12.1.3018 / 75c2cebff53eeee63fe7eafc5e31c188270d5fe8
2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarPython / 1.9.0.2010 / f17988b34c750c96c13ef5bdcc0645167233e3ad
 2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: Git / 1.3.0.869 / 4da53e3f9e55f4f2e5796625cb0c5768ed152079
 2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: SVN / 1.6.0.860 / 2111fdbd1dddda4ad6d4ed6486fd0b18c1010d3b
 2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarTS / 1.5.0.2122 / 7eb12e7593b8e02616914773451c6118f230c57a
 2018.04.05 09:09:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarXML / 1.4.3.1027 / 39588245cecf538bb27be4e496ff303b0143d20b
 2018.04.05 09:09:12 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.c.PostgresCharsetHandler] Verify that database charset supports UTF8
 2018.04.05 09:09:12 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.AutoDbMigration] Automatically perform DB migration on fresh install
```

So all is ok at the first run.

When i restart the server by docker ,

```
  2018.04.05 09:23:42 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.GeneratePluginIndex] Generate scanner plugin index
  2018.04.05 09:23:42 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterPlugins] Register plugins
 2018.04.05 09:23:42 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
 2018.04.05 09:23:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
 2018.04.05 09:23:52 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule Pylint:R0801
 2018.04.05 09:23:52 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:UselessParenthesesCheck
 2018.04.05 09:23:52 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:RightCurlyBraceSameLineAsNextBlockCheck
 2018.04.05 09:23:52 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule javascript:S138
 2018.04.05 09:23:52 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:S1764
 2018.04.05 09:23:52 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule csharpsquid:S112
```

Comment: Let's get the dumb questions out of the way first: do you actually have jar files in _$SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins_?

Comment: I am using the docker images without any updates

Comment: I tested with the sonarqube 6 and i have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of discrepancy between you image fs and config database on subsequent runs.

On first run, bundled plugins are copied from `/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins` into `/opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins` and marked as deployed in the **database**.
When you tear down your container and run it again, those plugins are missing from `/opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins`, as it's a clean slate again, but they are still marked as **deployed in database**. Sonar then assumes someone removed those plugins manually, and deletes them from a list of installed/deployed plugins.

This does not happen with H2 - being in memory and in the same image, it's state is also cleared on each restart.

The solution is to persist affected paths via volumes (and it's not only /plugins, but also /data as noted in linked [issue](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/112#issuecomment-338277087))

Based on https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/112#issuecomment-338277087 (*and to give it more visibility*)